# Format date in local language (moment.js)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Can you help me in formatting a UTC date into a textual representation in a local language (Dutch to be specific).

The code

```
var realDate = moment.utc(birthday);
var now = moment();
birthdayToday = (realDate.month() == now.month() && realDate.date() == now.date());
        data.Birthdays.push({
            Name: preferredName,
            Birthday: birthdayToday ? 'Today!' : realDate.format("MMMM D"),
            Path: path,
            PhotoUrl: photoUrl,
            AccountName: accountName,
            BirthdayIsToday: birthdayToday
        });
```

Because of the line realDate.format("MMMM D"), this current displays as May 31, June 6 etc.
What I want is 31 Mei, 6 Juni (dutch dates).

I dont see a clear example in the documentation on how to use format with a local language

Any help appreciated!

Comment: See the documentation for internationalization: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

Comment: Consider `realDate.lang('nl')` and `realDate.format('D MMMM')`. It seems you'll have to [add support](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-language/) for Dutch (nl) though as it doesn't seem to have [default support](http://momentjs.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var today = moment()
today.lang('de')
console.debug(today.calendar())
console.debug(moment().calendar())
```

Result:

```
Heute um 15:54 Uhr
Today at 3:54 PM
```

Remember to include `moment-with-langs.js` instead of the simple `moment.js`. Also remember that `.lang` provides **instance specific configuration**, so you will have to call `.lang('de')` for each moment instance that you want to use in German.

Or if you want **global** configuration:

```
moment.lang('de') //<-- call not on the instance, but on the moment function
var today = moment()
console.debug(today.calendar())
console.debug(moment().calendar())
```

Result:

```
Heute um 15:54 Uhr
Heute um 15:54 Uhr
```

[Moment with langs CDN](//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.6.0/moment-with-langs.js)

Answer (score 10):

Changing the locale globally:

```
moment.locale('nl');
```

And make sure you also load the **moment-with-locales.(min.)js** file

Answer (score 3):

You can change moment locale globally like that:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import localization from 'moment/locale/fr';

moment.locale('fr', localization);
```

I hope this helps you.